# Android App not compatible with devices

Tags: android

Hi am having an app in playstore and i have added below attributes in manifest to avoid this app installing in tablets.

```
   <!-- For Phone Only-->
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="small" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="420"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

</compatible-screens>
```

But after added this its not installing in Huawei Mate 8, Sony Xperia C6802 phones which are 6inch and 6.4 inch phones, I want to install the app in all phones not in tablets. How can i achieve this.?